# Why else part is getting executed 3 times?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Implementation of the singly linked list to count the number of nodes in the linked list.
 I have written the code to count a number of nodes in the singly linked list, it is counting correctly but else part statement is getting executed 3 times if I use the global count variable the same thing is happening. why it is so? I am using code blocks editor and I am getting output above mentioned.
I don't understand why else part is getting executed three times.
Please help to solve this problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct data
{
    int i;
    struct data *next;
};
//int count;
struct data *head=NULL;
void insert(int d)
{
    struct data *p;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        p=(struct data*)malloc(sizeof(struct data));
        p->i=d;
        p->next=NULL;
        head=p;
    }
    else
    {
        p=(struct data*)malloc(sizeof(struct data));
        struct data *temp;
        temp=head;
        while(temp->next!=NULL)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        temp->next=p;
        p->i=d;
        p->next=NULL;

    }
}
void disp(struct data *temp)
{
   if(temp==NULL)
   {
       return;
   }
   else
   {
      // printf("%d ",temp->i);//prints in forward direction
       disp(temp->next);
       printf("%d ",temp->i);//prints in reverse direction
   }
}
void countL(struct data *c)
{
    static int count;
    if(c==NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        count++;
        countL(c->next);

    }
    printf("\n");
    if(count==0)
    {
        printf("List is empty\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Number of nodes in the linked list are:%d\n",count);
    }
}
int main()
{
    insert(1);
    insert(2);
    insert(3);
    disp(head);
    countL(head);
}
```

Output:

```
3 2 1
Number of nodes in the linked list are:3

Number of nodes in the linked list are:3

Number of nodes in the linked list are:3
```

I have written the code to count a number of nodes in the singly linked list, it is counting correctly but else part statement is getting executed 3 times if I use the global count variable the same thing is happening. why it is so? I am using code blocks editor and I am getting output above mentioned.

Comment: Do you have a requirement to use recursion here? Since you used a while loop (`while(temp->next!=NULL)`) inside the `insert` function, I don't see why your count wouldn't do the same, i.e. `while (c != null) { count++; c = c->next; }`. Also your count function (why the "L" in `countL`?) should *return* the count as a value instead of printing it. And perhaps the biggest issue, `count` should not be static - if you call `countL` twice in a row, you will get the wrong value printed.

Comment: Yes..thanks..I am learning data structure so trying to use recursion also.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your printing `if`/`else` happens unconditionally every time `countL` is called. If you only want to call it once, you should move it inside the `if (c == NULL)` so it's only called when the list traversal terminates:

```
void countL(struct data *c)
{
    static int count;
    if (c == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n");
        if (count == 0)
        {
            printf("List is empty\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Number of nodes in the linked list are:%d\n", count);
        }
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        count++;
        countL(c->next);
    }
}
```

This way you get the output just once.